# Should you create multiple subnets for each Azure resource (CosmosDB, KeyVault, Storage) for VNET Private Endpoints or only use one?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-storage, azure-cognitive-search, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to follow tutorials on how to close down resources like dbs, storage accounts and KeyVaults behind a VNET. None of the tutorials address how you should create the subnets for multiple resources. From the docs I have seen they just create a subnet for functions, not for the resources. But from a blog I read, they made a subnet for the KeyVault. So I'm not really sure what to do here.

Right now I have couple of web apps, one function app that needs to connect to a KeyVault, storage account, CosmosDB and a Search Service. My plan was to create a subnet for:

- Web Apps
- Functions
- KeyVault
- Storage Account
- CosmosDB

Is this the way to go? Or do I only to create one for the functions? I read that these need to have their own subnet. Thanks for any help!

Comment: How do you intend to connect all these subnets? Typically, you put two resources that have to communicate in the same private subnet.

Comment: @MartinLiversage I thought that was handled by the VNET. So how would you go about connecting these? Just use one subnet for everything? Can't find any docs on this

Comment: What's your threat model? Generally more VNETs is safer because you segment your network. A breach of one resource only allow attacks on directly connected resources. That being said I would guess that both your web app and your functions need to connect to key vault, storage account and Cosmos DB which are the resources that you want to protect so it seems that everything might just as well be in a single VNET. 
If security is a concern to you then you should consult with a security expert which I'm not.

Comment: As long as we at least have some way to close down the resources, we are good. But the question still remains, do I make a subnet for each of the resources? https://blog.nillsf.com/index.php/2020/09/16/connect-azure-functions-securely-to-key-vault-using-vnet-integration-and-private-link/ in this tutorial, he creates a subnet for his KV. Does it make sense then to create one for each resource?

Comment: After skimming the article I better understand your question. I assume that you only want a single VNET. I don't know if it makes sense to create multiple subnets. Is _PrivateLink_ a feature only for key vault or is it supported by Cosmos DB? I don't know. However, it's generally safer to ensure that the different parts of your app communicates via a private VNET as it's described in the article. On the other hand the majority of apps out in the wild probably skips the VNET part. It comes down to the threat model...

Comment: Yeah CosmosDB, Storage and Search Services all support PL. We had a security firm recommend us to use VNET to lock down internal resources. Maybe overkill, but my orders are to set it up. But I'm new to both azure and networking, so was unsure about the subnet part. But thanks for the help, appreciate it!

Comment: If you have decided to connect everything using a VNET then just do that. I don't think subnets are a security feature but they will come out "naturally" as you set things up in Azure. I'm just guessing since I haven't done it myself but the procedure in the linked article created a couple of subnets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the same in my environment.

I created two web apps, a function app, storage account and key vault in the same region

I created a virtual network with three subnets.

I integrated web apps and function app with VNET Integration to two different subnets (subnet1 for web apps and subnet2 for function app) of the virtual network I created.

I created separate subnets for the function app and web apps because subnets are delegated to that particular service.

VNET Integration is for securely connect to resources in the virtual network from the web app or function app.

I created private endpoints for both Storage account and key vault in the same subnet (subnet3) of the virtual network I created.

We can use same subnet for different private endpoints. Also, we can create separate subnets for each private endpoint

I am able to connect to the storage account and key vault from the web app and function app

So in your case, you can create separate subnets for web apps, function app so they can be integrated with VNET.

You can create another subnet for all the private endpoints of the resources like key vault and storage account so that they can be accessed from the web apps and function app securely through the virtual network and private endpoints

For more information on private endpoints, you can refer this : [Azure virtual network service endpoints | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview)